# Why I can't access to this correctly initialized class property from the inside of this event handler function?

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am finding the following problem with Angular\TypeScript.

I have this class that handle the behavior of my component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { EventService } from '../event.service';
import interactionPlugin, { Draggable } from '@fullcalendar/interaction';

interface WorkShiftTypes {
  name: string;
  value: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-people-list',
  templateUrl: './people-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./people-list.component.css']
})
export class PeopleListComponent implements OnInit {

  people: any[];

  //cities: City[];

  workShiftTypes: WorkShiftTypes[];
  selectedShift: WorkShiftTypes;

  @ViewChild('draggable_people') draggablePeopleExternalElement: ElementRef;

  constructor(private eventService: EventService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.eventService.getPeople().then(people => {this.people = people;});

    this.selectedShift = {name: 'Mattina', value: 'Mattina'};

    this.workShiftTypes = [
      {name: 'Mattina', value: 'Mattina'},
      {name: 'Pomeriggio', value: 'Pomeriggio'},
      {name: 'Notte', value: 'Notte'},
      {name: 'Custom', value: 'Custom'}
    ];
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log("PEOPLE LIST ngAfterViewInit() START !!!")

    new Draggable(this.draggablePeopleExternalElement.nativeElement, {
      itemSelector: '.fc-event',
      eventData: function(eventEl) {
        console.log("DRAG !!!");
        console.log("SELECTED SHIFT: " + this.selectedShift.value);
        return {
          title: eventEl.innerText,
          selectedShift: this.selectedShift.value
        };
      }
    });

  }
}
```

As you can see in the previous code I have this property:

```
selectedShift: WorkShiftTypes;
```

that always contains a value (because I am setting it a default value into the **ngOnInit()** hook method and because it is bound to a PrimeNG component into my view.

Then I have this **ngAfterViewInit()** method hook:

ngAfterViewInit() {
console.log("PEOPLE LIST ngAfterViewInit() START !!!")

```
new Draggable(this.draggablePeopleExternalElement.nativeElement, {
  itemSelector: '.fc-event',
  eventData: function(eventEl) {
    console.log("DRAG !!!");
    console.log("SELECTED SHIFT: " + this.selectedShift.value);
    return {
      title: eventEl.innerText,
      selectedShift: this.selectedShift.value
    };
  }
});
```

Here I am creating a **Draggable** object in which is defined a callback function for the drag event (I am drag an item from a list and dropped this item into a calendar).

This function first try to print into the console log the value of the previous **this.selectedShift** class property and them I am trying to use this value to add a field to the returned object, by:

```
selectedShift: this.selectedShift.value
```

And on these two operation I have a problem. The code compile without error but trying to perform my application, when I try to drag an item from my list and drop it into my Calendar I obtain the following error message:

```
core.js:6272 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at ExternalElementDragging.eventData [as suppliedDragMeta] (people-list.component.ts:48)
    at ExternalElementDragging.push../node_modules/@fullcalendar/interaction/main.esm.js.ExternalElementDragging.buildDragMeta (main.esm.js:1916)
    at EmitterMixin.ExternalElementDragging.handleDragStart (main.esm.js:1830)
    at applyAll (main.esm.js:982)
    at EmitterMixin.push../node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.esm.js.EmitterMixin.triggerWith (main.esm.js:3576)
    at EmitterMixin.push../node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.esm.js.EmitterMixin.trigger (main.esm.js:3571)
    at EmitterMixin.HitDragging.handleDragStart (main.esm.js:991)
    at applyAll (main.esm.js:982)
    at EmitterMixin.push../node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.esm.js.EmitterMixin.triggerWith (main.esm.js:3576)
    at EmitterMixin.push../node_modules/@fullcalendar/core/main.esm.js.EmitterMixin.trigger (main.esm.js:3571)
```

It seems to me that form the inside of the **eventData: function(eventEl) { ...} event handler function it can't access to my **this.selectedShift** class property (is it because in this specific case the **this** refers to the Draggable object?). I am pretty sure of this because mooving this line:

```
console.log("SELECTED SHIFT: " + this.selectedShift.value);
```

outside of this function (for example as first line of the **ngAfterViewInit() hook function) I retrieve the correct default value set by the **ngOnInit()** function. So this value is correctly initialized.

Why I can't access to this property from the inside of this function? How can I access to it and fix my error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because of the scope of the eventData handler. 
You are not using an arrow function, so the context of `this` is binded to the caller.

You might want to use an arrow-function instead (context of arrow-functions are binded to its declartion):

```
eventData: (eventEl) => {
    console.log("DRAG !!!");
    console.log("SELECTED SHIFT: " + this.selectedShift.value);
    return {
      title: eventEl.innerText,
      selectedShift: this.selectedShift.value
    };
  }
```

Another way would be to use the bind function:

```
const handler = function(eventEl) {
        console.log("DRAG !!!");
        console.log("SELECTED SHIFT: " + this.selectedShift.value);
        return {
          title: eventEl.innerText,
          selectedShift: this.selectedShift.value
        };
      }

new Draggable(this.draggablePeopleExternalElement.nativeElement, {
  itemSelector: '.fc-event',
  eventData: handler.bind(this)
});
```